# Centos GUI not working

Tags: centos, gui

I installed centos 6.3 Final . But after rebooting it stuck and doesn't show GUI

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you need to start X-Windows manually.

1. Login on command prompt
2. run startx

Configuring to make it run automatically:

[X Window System](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/redhat/redhat5.2/5.2install-guide-dos/manual/doc054.htm)

Comment: sorry it didn't work. When i run the startx command it reply ***-bash: startx command not found***

Comment: Apparently "X Window System" is not installed on your VirtualBox to save space. You need to install it if you can't do without it.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue, but in my case it was too little RAM. (On about the 10th install attempt I saw a message flash up very briefly stating this).

It seems that if you have too little RAM or video memory it defaults to a text mode installer and does not install X.

1GB was enough (started with 512MB)

Answer (score 0):

Dear I also did this right after @Spackot reply but in vain.

It gave me some repositories error although I was connected to internet but still it happened.So i simply reinstalled centos.

**But this time I checked the video memory settings. And there were only 1MB memory assigned by default so I assigned 70MB and also selected 3rd option while Booting. Which is Install OS which Basic Video drivers and it worked.**